# Sending Binary Data problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send binary data from a database over an ASP.NET page. I can see that the property data.Length is 2400, that means 2400 bytes, right?
The weird thing is that when i receive this data the size is ~4kb, and appears to be corrupted. Any idea what the problem might be?

```
byte[] data = proxy.getData(id);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.bin");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.Write(data);
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Non-withstanding the answer I've posted, have you verified that `data` contains what you're expecting? I've written similar code before and spent ages trying to work out why the downloaded file was wrong, when it was actually the data I was sending down that was duff! =)

Comment: I've verified it by actually writing the content to a file and then redirecting to that file so that it prompts me to download it :) Not the best of solutions but it showed me that the data was valid. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 4 overloads of Response.Write:

```
public void Write(char ch);
public void Write(object obj);
public void Write(string s);
public void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count);
```

And I would suspect that, based on your code (`Response.Write(data)`), that you're calling the `object obj` overload. Have you tried:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

This is specifically intended for writing the contents of a byte array to the output stream.